# How to deal with byte operators in Golang?

Tags: go, networking, buffer, packets

I would like to create a buffer which will contain information like nickname and password. Let's say I have created empty buffer, which is

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

By then I would like to fill it up with data, like
`buffer << nickname(string) << password(string)`, so in result I'm getting

```
08 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 08 70 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64
```

which is `len.nickname actual_nickname len.password password`

Now, after I have created such buffer I would like to parse it to variables.
That would look like `buffer >> nickname(string) >> password(string)`

I made something once in c++ which was using operators, but I am not sure how to do so in Golang.

These buffers would be used as packets body in my networking app. I don't want to use structs, but kind of above.

I hope I explained my issue properly. I also do not want to use splitters like `:` to get these into array table.

Thank you.

Comment: p.s. not sure why people downvotes this question, since this issue does not seem to be easy as it seems.

Comment: You want to write arbitrary bytes into a buffer and be able to parse it back, but you don't want separators. Then you'll have to store a length before the actual data. Better yet, use a common encoding (json, protobuf, gob, etc...). And please show what you're tried, we won't just write the code for you. Maybe try [binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/).

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the anwser. That's what I was able to do in C++ with operators, but since I can't define them in Golang I was wondering if there is other way than using structs or protobuf/json.

Comment: Take a look at the binary package mentioned above. It gives you convenient methods to read/write fixed-sized numbers, and has lots of examples. You were asking why the downvotes? Probably because you didn't do any research.

Comment: Would you please show the c++ code? I am quite curious at how do you manage to store byte without separators and length of data.

Comment: @sadlyconfused don't take the downvotes personally; the golang community on this website tends to aggressively downvote questions and answers, regardless of their validity, helpfulness, or general usefulness.

Comment: @leafbebop I have used offsets calculation by variable type.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer), to which you can write as necessary, including using [`fmt.Fprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) if necessary. When everything is written to the buffer, you can get the bytes back out.

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
fmt.Fprint(buf, nickname)
fmt.Fprint(buf, password)
fmt.Print(buf.Bytes())
```

Working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/bRL6-N-3qH_n

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question which asks about a way to get the data back.

Answer (score -1):

You can do fixed-size encoding using the [encoding/binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package, including choosing endianness.

The example below writes two strings preceded by the length stored as a `uint32` in network byte order. This would be appropriate to send over the wire. You can use `uint16`, or even `uint8` if you're certain this will be enough to represent the string lengths.

**Warning**: I'm ignoring all errors in this sample code. Please do not do that in yours.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    user := "foouser"
    password := "barpassword"

    // Write "len(user) user len(password) password".
    // Lengths are unsigned 32 bit ints in network byte order.
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, (uint32)(len(user)))
    buf.WriteString(user)
    binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, (uint32)(len(password)))
    buf.WriteString(password)

    var output []byte = buf.Bytes()
    fmt.Printf("% x\n", output)

    // Now read it back (we could use the buffer,
    // but let's use Reader for clarity)
    input := bytes.NewReader(output)
    var uLen, pLen uint32

    binary.Read(input, binary.BigEndian, &uLen)
    uBytes := make([]byte, uLen)
    input.Read(uBytes)
    newUser := string(uBytes)

    binary.Read(input, binary.BigEndian, &pLen)
    pBytes := make([]byte, pLen)
    input.Read(pBytes)
    newPassword := string(pBytes)

    fmt.Printf("User: %q, Password: %q", newUser, newPassword)
}
```

This outputs the byte array and the strings extracted from it:

```
00 00 00 07 66 6f 6f 75 73 65 72 00 00 00 0b 62 61 72 70 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64
User: "foouser", Password: "barpassword"
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/crLkz-_Gzuu)